# I already have a black and white optical flow image, how do I turn it into color with this code?

Tags: python

**How do I put the  optical flow pictures into this code?**

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

cap= cv.VideoCapture("vtest,avi")
ret,frame1=cap.read()
prvs=cv.cvtColor(frame1.cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
hsv=np.zeros_like(frame1)
hsv[...,1]=255

while(1):
    ret,frame2=cap.read()
    next=cv,cv.Color(frame2,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    flow=cv.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prvs,next,None, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0)
    mag,ang=cv.cartToPolar(flow[...,0],flow[...,1])

    hsv[...,0]=ang*180/np.pi/2 #角度
    hsv[...,2]=cv.normalize(mag,None,0,255,cv.NORM_MINMAX)
    bgr=cv.cvtColor(hsv,cv.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    cv.imshow("frame2",bgr)
    cv.imshow("frame1",frame2)
    k=cv.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k==27:
        break
    elif k==ord("s"):
        cv.imwrite("opticalfb.png",frame2)
        cv.imwrite("opticalhsv.png",bgr)
    prvs=next
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

**I tried putting cap= cv.VideoCapture("vtest,avi") into the optical flow image and still have the problem.**